# How to insure proper alignment for two layer geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I am struggling to plot circles in a `ggplot` **exactly** on top of each other.

Here is the plot code:

```
xx = ggplot(dfm2, aes(x = variable, y = tax)) + 
      geom_point(aes(size = sqrt(value),color = phyla), shape = 21) + 
      scale_size_continuous(limits = c(0, 35), range = c(1,20)) + 
      theme(legend.key=element_blank(), 
            axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, angle = 90, vjust = 0.3, hjust = 1), 
            axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold", size = 8), 
            legend.text = element_text(size = 10, face ="bold", colour ="black"), 
            legend.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"), 
            panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1.2), 
            legend.position = "right") 
    
    xx
```

My data frame:

```
dfm2 <- structure(list(tax = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 
16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
18L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L), .Label = c("Clavulina", "Cortinarius", 
"Piloderma", "Russula", "Xerocomellus", "Atheliaceae", "Boletaceae", 
"Clavulinaceae", "Cortinariaceae", "Thelephoraceae", "Boletales", 
"Cantharellales", "Russulales", "Cenococcum", "Cladophialophora", 
"Elaphomyces", "Elaphomycetaceae", "Herpotrichiellaceae", "Chaetothyriales", 
"Eurotiales", "Helotiaceae", "Pezizales", "Sordariales", "Umbelopsidales"
), class = "factor"), test = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("g", 
"f", "o"), class = "factor"), phyla = c("Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Dothideomycetes", "Dothideomycetes", 
"Dothideomycetes", "Dothideomycetes", "Dothideomycetes", "Dothideomycetes", 
"Dothideomycetes", "Dothideomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Leotiomycetes", "Leotiomycetes", 
"Leotiomycetes", "Leotiomycetes", "Leotiomycetes", "Leotiomycetes", 
"Leotiomycetes", "Leotiomycetes", "Pezizomycetes", "Pezizomycetes", 
"Pezizomycetes", "Pezizomycetes", "Pezizomycetes", "Pezizomycetes", 
"Pezizomycetes", "Pezizomycetes", "Sordariomycetes", "Sordariomycetes", 
"Sordariomycetes", "Sordariomycetes", "Sordariomycetes", "Sordariomycetes", 
"Sordariomycetes", "Sordariomycetes", "Umbelopsidomycetes", "Umbelopsidomycetes", 
"Umbelopsidomycetes", "Umbelopsidomycetes", "Umbelopsidomycetes", 
"Umbelopsidomycetes", "Umbelopsidomycetes", "Umbelopsidomycetes"
), phyla1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Leotiomycetes", 
"Leotiomycetes", "Leotiomycetes", "Leotiomycetes", "Leotiomycetes", 
"Leotiomycetes", "Leotiomycetes", "Leotiomycetes", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), phyla2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", 
"Agaricomycetes", "Agaricomycetes", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
"Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", "Eurotiomycetes", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Pezizomycetes", "Pezizomycetes", 
"Pezizomycetes", "Pezizomycetes", "Pezizomycetes", "Pezizomycetes", 
"Pezizomycetes", "Pezizomycetes", "Sordariomycetes", "Sordariomycetes", 
"Sordariomycetes", "Sordariomycetes", "Sordariomycetes", "Sordariomycetes", 
"Sordariomycetes", "Sordariomycetes", "Umbelopsidomycetes", "Umbelopsidomycetes", 
"Umbelopsidomycetes", "Umbelopsidomycetes", "Umbelopsidomycetes", 
"Umbelopsidomycetes", "Umbelopsidomycetes", "Umbelopsidomycetes"
), variable = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("KAC", "KAF", "KAW", 
"GRC", "BHC"), class = "factor"), value = c(0, 0, 55.722420779792, 
16.7351551362146, 130.651761638796, 47.4630290758812, 344.253315259547, 
179.599304875006, 9.54521273810036, 4.17856131969448, 0, 0, 10.1906702027936, 
4.67675794099578, 16.4389432505032, 6.56146785828124, 292.554112042119, 
192.444415108634, 240.314439785311, 113.567323164539, 6.63551229846123, 
2.42876606836088, 0.340378846018673, 0.124587304553666, 31.9637482669779, 
11.6995438658847, 301.162822135619, 166.339660106073, 15.9968898677191, 
10.158845171958, 119.003045585602, 44.1241465067143, 314.898113957191, 
115.827941884529, 11.6466634606362, 4.26297469592084, 78.9008308713511, 
44.6641400711928, 28.5922537488445, 15.0910261581729, 130.729467450933, 
47.6893792546978, 9.54684330461525, 4.19471614756479, 4.99564959212625, 
1.37026614431018, 58.2838435666646, 19.6026370831945, 32.8298602817313, 
17.9016604233309, 18.5327625920274, 10.4521875380684, 240.314439785311, 
113.567323164539, 19.4803542613531, 7.60127408652835, 10.2807970505094, 
4.71425747225164, 36.5303309999698, 15.4344619154041, 34.5717196916383, 
16.9962815569886, 18.5538892372794, 13.4818901076747, 6.63551229846123, 
2.42876606836088, 0.340378846018673, 0.124587304553666, 0, 0, 
11.7535135841283, 4.30208455551645, 28.5922537488445, 15.0910261581729, 
120.936072922602, 44.8317152093529, 330.592974987903, 137.987570972834, 
81.7656524037499, 30.777185859533, 11.8043759923957, 5.97910730494584, 
9.59655917970584, 3.92673043588229, 359.029012230497, 198.094178611349, 
240.292352409899, 114.031257835764, 80.00005954321, 29.8311568640691, 
296.527500155951, 250.98810836895, 18.5538892372794, 13.4818901076747, 
6.65236646087093, 2.5325888221556, 298.92445563979, 169.429423759217, 
92.7194563191488, 52.403869281338, 126.532038941658, 47.2411841059221, 
111.963490509424, 73.9167204244325, 50.4347790386522, 21.1562679516175, 
30.3384280807787, 12.0523745796255, 36.7115313609751, 17.9442186599375, 
0, 0, 5.35622404345806, 2.4642318970895, 139.58823304089, 40.275439916366, 
71.9233658127593, 23.2361293322448, 9.31141084543879, 2.69935890226071, 
33.2859896258468, 15.279240235619, 122.935605593244, 59.1332236269826, 
19.0839243507556, 11.0072228505803, 0, 0, 139.58823304089, 40.275439916366, 
8.67831225770859, 4.80994940565981, 9.31141084543879, 2.69935890226071, 
85.8858328927752, 28.3822536421699, 123.949404659904, 97.825605551247, 
33.5449967797736, 17.6443721997637, 0, 0, 23.6716255982153, 16.5406062730736, 
35.1404871014572, 21.6910522326589, 153.002145966387, 46.1587735277285, 
137.878633245296, 65.7492431345792, 23.8561518165481, 10.8236490366025, 
46.2039777568, 28.944729324695, 159.114066407422, 120.326178107811, 
52.2354005195345, 33.6610167992512, 11.2151836173417, 7.02663183495428, 
48.8646545919587, 35.3190572925153, 63.0368483186293, 30.8250803868248, 
127.444871057481, 68.2274750668282, 28.5426593569714, 16.7932976872273, 
49.3303009891819, 24.774068855448, 15.8101618958304, 10.2555714159122, 
1.28517298118379, 0.562918778911717, 31.2190858156308, 17.8727837772257, 
7.10547842444747, 4.32510661848181, 21.139683447186, 9.89224632770911, 
46.4617671152079, 21.9653240368642, 66.746547931994, 42.9018737315692, 
56.0146095178226, 35.5807654007847, 26.8443827302432, 18.3445503760626, 
54.8834055701279, 22.5921210691608, 28.1767798117358, 16.3740739812223
)), row.names = c(147L, 155L, 156L, 148L, 158L, 150L, 159L, 151L, 
160L, 152L, 195L, 203L, 204L, 196L, 206L, 198L, 207L, 199L, 208L, 
200L, 59L, 51L, 60L, 52L, 62L, 54L, 63L, 55L, 64L, 56L, 11L, 
3L, 12L, 4L, 14L, 6L, 15L, 7L, 16L, 8L, 169L, 161L, 170L, 162L, 
171L, 163L, 172L, 164L, 176L, 168L, 217L, 209L, 218L, 210L, 219L, 
211L, 220L, 212L, 224L, 216L, 73L, 65L, 74L, 66L, 75L, 67L, 76L, 
68L, 72L, 80L, 25L, 17L, 26L, 18L, 27L, 19L, 28L, 20L, 32L, 24L, 
185L, 177L, 186L, 178L, 190L, 182L, 233L, 225L, 234L, 226L, 238L, 
230L, 89L, 81L, 90L, 82L, 94L, 86L, 41L, 33L, 42L, 34L, 46L, 
38L, 153L, 145L, 201L, 193L, 57L, 49L, 1L, 9L, 154L, 146L, 157L, 
149L, 202L, 194L, 205L, 197L, 58L, 50L, 61L, 53L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 
13L, 173L, 165L, 175L, 167L, 221L, 213L, 223L, 215L, 77L, 69L, 
79L, 71L, 21L, 29L, 31L, 23L, 187L, 179L, 188L, 180L, 235L, 227L, 
236L, 228L, 91L, 83L, 92L, 84L, 43L, 35L, 44L, 36L, 174L, 166L, 
222L, 214L, 78L, 70L, 30L, 22L, 189L, 181L, 237L, 229L, 93L, 
85L, 45L, 37L, 191L, 183L, 239L, 231L, 95L, 87L, 47L, 39L, 192L, 
184L, 240L, 232L, 96L, 88L, 48L, 40L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the plot:

[image]

I need the circles to be centered several of them are slightly shifted.
I have tried a number of calls for `position =` but nothing successful.

Any ideas?

Session info:

```
>sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 14393)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.0               stringr_1.4.0               purrr_0.3.4                 readr_1.4.0                
 [5] tibble_3.0.4                tidyverse_1.3.0             genefilter_1.72.0           plyr_1.8.6                 
 [9] metagenomeSeq_1.32.0        RColorBrewer_1.1-2          glmnet_4.0-2                Matrix_1.2-18              
[13] limma_3.46.0                ggrepel_0.9.0               dplyr_1.0.2                 funrar_1.4.1               
[17] qdapTools_1.3.5             dendextend_1.14.0           ggplot2_3.3.3               vegan_2.5-7                
[21] lattice_0.20-41             permute_0.9-5               reshape_0.8.8               viridis_0.5.1              
[25] viridisLite_0.3.0           tidyr_1.1.2                 DESeq2_1.30.0               SummarizedExperiment_1.20.0
[29] MatrixGenerics_1.2.0        matrixStats_0.57.0          GenomicRanges_1.42.0        GenomeInfoDb_1.26.2        
[33] IRanges_2.24.1              S4Vectors_0.28.1            vsn_3.58.0                  Biobase_2.50.0             
[37] BiocGenerics_0.36.0         phyloseq_1.34.0             apeglm_1.12.0              

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] colorspace_2.0-0       ellipsis_0.3.1         XVector_0.30.0         fs_1.5.0              
  [5] rstudioapi_0.13        farver_2.0.3           affyio_1.60.0          bit64_4.0.5           
  [9] fansi_0.4.1            lubridate_1.7.9.2      AnnotationDbi_1.52.0   mvtnorm_1.1-1         
 [13] xml2_1.3.2             codetools_0.2-16       splines_4.0.3          geneplotter_1.68.0    
 [17] ade4_1.7-16            jsonlite_1.7.2         broom_0.7.3            annotate_1.68.0       
 [21] dbplyr_2.0.0           cluster_2.1.0          BiocManager_1.30.10    compiler_4.0.3        
 [25] httr_1.4.2             backports_1.2.0        assertthat_0.2.1       cli_2.2.0             
 [29] prettyunits_1.1.1      tools_4.0.3            igraph_1.2.6           coda_0.19-4           
 [33] gtable_0.3.0           glue_1.4.2             GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.4 affy_1.68.0           
 [37] reshape2_1.4.4         Rcpp_1.0.5             bbmle_1.0.23.1         cellranger_1.1.0      
 [41] vctrs_0.3.6            Biostrings_2.58.0      rhdf5filters_1.2.0     multtest_2.46.0       
 [45] ape_5.4-1              preprocessCore_1.52.1  nlme_3.1-149           iterators_1.0.13      
 [49] rvest_0.3.6            lifecycle_0.2.0        gtools_3.8.2           XML_3.99-0.5          
 [53] zlibbioc_1.36.0        MASS_7.3-53            scales_1.1.1           hms_0.5.3             
 [57] biomformat_1.18.0      rhdf5_2.34.0           memoise_1.1.0          gridExtra_2.3         
 [61] emdbook_1.3.12         bdsmatrix_1.3-4        stringi_1.5.3          RSQLite_2.2.2         
 [65] foreach_1.5.1          caTools_1.18.0         BiocParallel_1.24.1    shape_1.4.5           
 [69] chron_2.3-56           rlang_0.4.10           pkgconfig_2.0.3        bitops_1.0-6          
 [73] Wrench_1.8.0           Rhdf5lib_1.12.0        labeling_0.4.2         bit_4.0.4             
 [77] tidyselect_1.1.0       magrittr_2.0.1         R6_2.5.0               gplots_3.1.1          
 [81] generics_0.1.0         DelayedArray_0.16.0    DBI_1.1.0              haven_2.3.1           
 [85] pillar_1.4.7           withr_2.3.0            mgcv_1.8-33            survival_3.2-7        
 [89] RCurl_1.98-1.2         modelr_0.1.8           crayon_1.3.4           KernSmooth_2.23-17    
 [93] progress_1.2.2         readxl_1.3.1           locfit_1.5-9.4         grid_4.0.3            
 [97] data.table_1.13.6      blob_1.2.1             reprex_0.3.0           digest_0.6.27         
[101] xtable_1.8-4           numDeriv_2016.8-1.1    munsell_0.5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the same behaviour in R on Windows when plotting to the screen. However, I've found that the problem doesn't occur in the file saved using `ggsave()`. This might be an option for your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed the issue is gone, but only when exporting as one of the non-editable image formats (png, tiff etc.). I normally export as emf-files, so that I can trim the final layout in PowerPoint, but when I choose this option, the problem is back.... Hhm, I can't have it all it seems. But thank you so much for this solution, it will definitely help me in other situations.

Comment: I'm not seeing the same. Rstudio 1.4, R 4.0.3, using AGG for graphics, default antialiasing.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in Rstudio if the graphics backend is "Windows", otherwise, they look fine. If I save a good-looking plot with `ggsave("plot.emf")`, and put it into powerpoint, then it looks messy again.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting, I can't replicate the problem.  When I use your data with your code I get the following plot:

[image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.3.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.11  magrittr_2.0.1   tidyselect_1.1.0 munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_1.4-1 R6_2.5.0         rlang_0.4.10    
 [8] blob_1.2.1       dplyr_1.0.3      tools_4.0.3      grid_4.0.3       packrat_0.5.0    gtable_0.3.0     DBI_1.1.0       
[15] withr_2.2.0      ellipsis_0.3.1   digest_0.6.27    assertthat_0.2.1 tibble_3.0.5     lifecycle_0.2.0  crayon_1.3.4    
[22] purrr_0.3.4      farver_2.0.3     vctrs_0.3.6      glue_1.4.2       labeling_0.3     compiler_4.0.3   pillar_1.4.7    
[29] generics_0.1.0   scales_1.1.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3 
>
```

Comment: That is very weird. I run in RStudio, but I just tried to run the code"directly" in R, it makes no difference for me, I get the same wrong result. I will add session info to my question. I see we have the same version etc. but you run on Mac and I on Windows. Why is Windows ALWAYS stupid....

Comment: @Mathilde I was also working in RStudio.  I'll give it a try on my Windows VM a bit later this morning if no other Windows user chimes in.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I am kinda having the same issue in PowerPoint I wanted to align the circles manually (because well, got to move on). But after going in and aligning each pair of circles vertical and horizontal, when I zoom out and look at the whole plot, the shifts are back! Aaargh!! So I am thinking it must be some graphic capacity limitation of my PC... - although I never encountered that before....

Comment: @Mathilde I'm happy to export what I've got in whatever format you want if that would be helpful.

Comment: That is a very nice offer, thank you! However, I am gonna make 1000x changes to these plots still, but now I at least partially have a solution based on the others comments. So I will manage, but thank you!

Comment: Try saving an EMF on your Mac, and then inserting it into a powerpoint on your Windows VM. I think it may be a windows rendering issue. I'm on windows and can get a good looking plot in Rstudio using the AGG backend, but when exporting to EMF and then to Powerpoint, I get non-concentric circles.

Answer (score 1):

Same result as Mathilde on my Windows machine.

Fixed with `ggsave` as noted  by Miff

[image]

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.3.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13  magrittr_2.0.1   tidyselect_1.1.0 munsell_0.5.0   
 [5] colorspace_2.0-0 R6_2.5.0         rlang_0.4.9      stringr_1.4.0   
 [9] dplyr_1.0.2      tools_4.0.3      grid_4.0.3       gtable_0.3.0    
[13] xfun_0.19        tinytex_0.28     withr_2.3.0      ellipsis_0.3.1  
[17] digest_0.6.27    tibble_3.0.4     lifecycle_0.2.0  crayon_1.3.4    
[21] purrr_0.3.4      farver_2.0.3     vctrs_0.3.6      glue_1.4.2      
[25] labeling_0.4.2   stringi_1.5.3    compiler_4.0.3   pillar_1.4.7    
[29] generics_0.1.0   scales_1.1.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3
```